# stateParams not available when I call state.go()

Tags: angularjs

So I am having trouble with stateParams - I have done this before and have never had an issue but I can't seem to pass anything to the state when I call go.

If you look at the demographics section you can see that I am returning a function for the template URL and it works just fine when I hard code the GUID however my personId variable is always undefined. I am trying to figure out what I have done to cause this however I can't for the life of me.

```
memberApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('quickScreen', {
        url: "#/Components/QuickScreen",
        templateUrl: "/Components/QuickScreen/index.html",
        controller: "quickScreenController",
    });

    $stateProvider.state('quickScreen.detail', {
        url: '#/quickScreen/:step',
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams.step);
            return "/Components/QuickScreen/" + $stateParams.step + "/" + $stateParams.step + ".html";
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('demographics', {
        views: {
            "memberDemographics": {  
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                    console.log("PersonId: " + $stateParams.personId);
                    //return '/Demographics/Index/' + $stateParams.personId;
                    return '/Demographics/Index/' + 'f75fb494-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a17b01336ca5';
                },
                controller: 'demographicsSearchController'
            }
        },

    });
});

memberApp.controller('memberAppController', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

    console.log("About to load to demographics");
    $state.go('demographics', { personId: 'f75fb494-fe7a-4564-be93-a17b01336ca5' });
});
```

Comment: Right, because I didn't want the URL to change - what I just figured out is that I need to include params { personId: {}} in the state configuration. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this ,We can take Particular Id from stateParams and assign to some variable you can use that variable or u can user direactly
( $state.go('demographics', { personId: $stateParams.personId });).

```
memberApp.controller('memberAppController','$stateParams','$scope','$scope',
 function ($scope,$state, $stateParams)
 {
     console.log("About to load to demographics");
     var Id = $stateParams.personId;   
     $state.go('demographics', { personId: Id });        
});
```

Comment: Right that works - this is an issue with ui-serf, I can see the personId in the link but it isn't getting put into state params.